# R replace logical vector with "on" or "off"

Tags: r, vector, replace

I'm trying to create a one liner that will replace a logical vector with "on" or "off" based on true or false.

Best I've been able to come up with is using 2 gsubs.

Assuming I have the vector tmp

```
tmp <- sample(100,100)
```

I can use

```
blah <- tmp > 50
blah <- gsub(FALSE, "no", blah)
blah <- gsub(TRUE, "yes", blah)
```

to achieve what I want, but I'm betting there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Not sure if you would consider more elegant but you can nest gsub calls: `blah <- gsub(FALSE, "no", gsub(TRUE, "yes", blah))`

Comment: I wanted to avoid the nested gsubs. ping's answer down below is exactly what I was looking for when I posted. 

akrun's answers are actually really interesting to know as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using `ifelse`:

```
blah <- ifelse(tmp > 50, "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
r1 <- c('no', 'yes')[(tmp>50)+1]
identical(r1, blah)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
 r2 <- as.character(factor(tmp>50, labels=c('no', 'yes')))
 identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
 library(qdap)
 r3 <-  mgsub(c(FALSE, TRUE), c('no', 'yes'), tmp > 50)
 identical(r1,r3)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
 library(car)
 r4 <- recode(tmp>50, "FALSE='no'; TRUE='yes'")
 identical(r1,r4)
 #[1] TRUE
```